How to check another installation is running
I have automated installation of SQL Server(last step is server reboot).
Next step is installation of SSMS which fails with:
 Failed to grab execution mutex. System error 258.

According to docs the problem is:

Cause:
This error can been caused by one to the following: Msiexec.exe
process is already running on the machine The registry string
PendingFileRenameOperations is currently populated and the computer is
waiting to be restarted.

If I just re-execute SSMS install it succeeds. Is there a way how to detect, that some installation or update is currently running on Windows Server?
Is there a way how to wait till installation is possible?

You can test wether a specific process is running or not with:
$Name = 'Msiexec.exe'
Get-Process $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

So the following should block until the process ends or 2 minutes have passed:
for($iteration = 0; $iteration -lt 60; $iteration++)
{
    Write-Progress "Waiting for the process $description to end..." -Status "Waiting" -PercentComplete (($iteration * 100) / 60)
    Sleep -Seconds 2

    $processes = @(Get-Process $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($processes.Count -eq 0) {
        return;
    }
}


I like to use the module pendingreboot from PSGallery to help me out in such occasions.
Install-Module pendingreboot


This function will query the registry on a local and/or remote computer and determine if the system is pending a reboot, from Microsoft/Windows updates, Configuration Manager Client SDK, Pending Computer Rename, Domain Join, Pending File Rename Operations and Component Based Servicing.

PS> Test-PendingReboot

ComputerName IsRebootPending
------------ ---------------
YourHostName            True

If you just want to wait for any current msiexec to finish first, run
Wait-Process msiexec -TimeOut 120

If it time outs, you can choose what to do by handling the error using a try - catch structure.
